# Open source for Quadrocopter

Tags: machine-learning

Are there any open source projects or part of codes using which its possible to control quadrocopter (simple or advanced movement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/arducopter/

Arduino-based autopilot for mulitrotor craft, from quadcopters to traditional helis

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/openpilot/OpenPilot
Open pilot software to control copters, helicopters, wings, etc.